# Chrome uses different versions of HTTP randomly

Tags: google-chrome, http, http2, http-1.1

I have a website that supports HTTP2. If I use Firefox or Chrome in anonymous mode then all the calls are made with HTTP2 (shown as h2 in Chrome developer tools Network tab).

When I use ordinary Chrome though it does exactly the same call but uses HTTP1.1 for some reason. I have tried to turn of all extensions but it is still HTTP1.1.

Sometimes if I restart Chrome is starts using HTTP2 again but then falls back to HTTP 1.1 after a while or after one of the restarts. I cannot figure out what can be the problem and it looks very mysterious.

I did not change any settings explicitly in Chrome if they even exist. What can be the problem here?

P.S. I did "clear browser cache" and "clear browser cookies" and suddenly I got only http2, don't know how this ca affect protocol. This was a temporary improvement though and I got http1.1 after a while again

P.P.S. I have even got a case when loading a website that one request was http1.1 but the other one was http2 to exactly same server.

Comment: Presume it’s not showing content cached under HTTP/2? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430166/why-part-of-my-http-requests-do-not-use-http2

Comment: Or a service worker?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513933/requests-served-from-serviceworker-are-downgraded-from-http-2-to-http-1-1

Comment: No service worker and I did use "no cache" option, but I will double check, perhaps that is the issue

Comment: I have double checked, it is not cache that is shown as http 1.1, even with "disable cache" option I get http1.1 sometimes for some reason

Comment: "clear browser cache" and "clear browser cookies" fixed it somehow...

Comment: There is not enough information here and the only answers given will be wild guesses.

Comment: Well, just say the word, I don't even know what other information I can provide...

Comment: Just chiming in, I've done a bunch of HTTP/1.1 vs HTTP/2 benchmarking and I've also seen this and could not really figure out a pattern. Sometimes everything goes over HTTP/1.1

Comment: This is very strange, I am really wondering if this is happening with ordinary users as well or it has to do something with the developer "things" we do...