# How does Chromium/Chrome decide to use wether http/2 or http/1.1

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, http2

we encountered a weird problem in which we work on a SAP server that has HTTP/2 enabled.
If we try to access the system (e.g. a BSP), different Browsers show different protocols.

- Firefox 84.0.2 - HTTP/2
- Internet Explorer 11 - HTTP/2
- Chrome 87.0.4280.141  - HTTP/1.1
- Edge 87.0.664.75 - HTTP/1.1

As of right now we cannot think of a reason for this behaviour. It seems like Chrome/Chromium behaves different to the other browser. This made us think about the mechanism Chrome/Chromium uses to select the protocol version.

Does anyone have any insight into that mechanism? I could not anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Tiny addition: Chrome in incognito mode does use HTTP/2 as well

Comment: Are you viewing cached content perhaps that was downloaded before the sever was upgraded to HTTP/2? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430166/why-part-of-my-http-requests-do-not-use-http2

Comment: We cleared everything without any difference.

Comment: Using a Service Worker? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513933/requests-served-from-serviceworker-are-downgraded-from-http-2-to-http-1-1/54515338

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there is a known Bug in the Chromium Code https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=832586 .

Somehow Chrome does fall back to HTTP/1.1 when using SPNego/ Kerberos.